# tar command changing the owner:group while extracting

Tags: linux, ubuntu

While extracting a file using this command `tar -zxf bluez-arm-package.tgz` the owner(1000):group(pulse) of the files and directories is 
changing as below example.

Example:

```
drwxrwxr-x    4 1000     pulse         1024 Jul 21 00:32 dbus-1
```

The actual should be:

```
drwxrwxr-x    4 root     root          1024 Jul 21 00:32 dbus-1
```

Comment: Please also include the user which is executing the command.

Comment: `tar` was originally designed as a backup tool. By default it saves and restores the owner, group and file permissions.

Comment: hear the user is root

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264464/sudo-tar-changes-extracted-files-ownership-to-unknown-user

Answer (score 21):

There is an option for output stream in tar : `--no-same-owner`

So

```
tar xvf test_tar.tar --no-same-owner
```

will probably create files with user who launch this command as owner.
It's a little bit strange as this option (--no-same-owner) should be default for ordinary (non-superuser) users.

Does it work for you?

Comment: Ah... didn' realise that you launch tar as root. For root the default is --same-owner