# Tar issue with long option through SSH

Tags: ssh, tar

I am using a ssh connection to unarchive a remote tar.gz and i am getting an error using `−−no−same−owner`.
Here is the command:

```
ssh -i "$SERVER_KEY" -C "$SSH_STRING" -p "$SERVER_PORT" "tar -xf '/path/to/archive.tar.gz' -C '/path/to/unarchive' −−no−same−owner";
```

I am getting the following message:

> tar: \342\210\222\342\210\222no\342\210\222same\342\210\222owner: Not found in archive
>
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Without this option, this is working fine and running it with a ssh console is also working fine.

NB: I am executing these commands between 2 Ubuntu servers on 2 Virtualbox VMs on my Windows workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashes in your "−−no−same−owner" string are UTF-8 [unicode minus](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm) characters:

```
% echo '−−no−same−owner' | od -t x1c
0000000    e2  88  92  e2  88  92  6e  6f  e2  88  92  73  61  6d  65  e2
           −  **  **   −  **  **   n   o   −  **  **   s   a   m   e   −
0000020    88  92  6f  77  6e  65  72  0a                                
          **  **   o   w   n   e   r  \n                                
0000030
```

"e2 88 92" is the UTF-8 encoding of U+2212, the minus sign.

Tar is isn't recognizing "−−no−same−owner" as a command-line option because it doesn't start with the [ASCII dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) which normally marks command-line options. It's treating it as a filename instead.

Maybe you copied and pasted "−−no−same−owner" from a word processing document?

Comment: Thank you, I replaced the characters and now this is working pretty well !
It was copy/pasted from another stackoverflow topic => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507466/tar-command-changing-the-ownergroup-while-extracting